# Размножение текста в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Как размножить текст в PHPStorm?

---

Пример:

- ввожу `-`;
- нажимаю некую комбинацию горячих клавиш;
- ввожу число `30`;
- нажимаю `Enter`;
- получаю `------------------------------`.

---

Наподобие как в Vim.

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать IdeaVim плагин: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164

Answer (score 1):

**'File | Settings | Editor | Live Templates'**

Там же есть возможность создавать свои выражения, используя переменные.

Comment: Я активно пользюсь Live Templates, вот именно поэтому и возник вопрос :) На данный момент я сделал сниппеты аля `-40`, `-80` etc, которые рарскрываются в соответствующее количество символов, но возможно есть плагин какой-то или эта фича «вшита» в JetBrains, а мы не знаем :)

Comment: Вот, кстати, не знаете случаем, почему они могут не импортироваться? То есть я экспортирую настройки с одного PHPStorm (смотрел: внутри архива они (шаблоны) есть) и импортирую в другой: все настройки применяются, кроме моих `Live Templates`. Пробовал также и через `Settings Repository...` — та же беда?